# Almost prime with O(1)? (faux prime algorithm)

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms

I know/guess there aren't any algorithm that produces prime numbers without an ever increasing algorithmic complexity.

But are there any successful attempts to produce a single algorithm that is close to prime? I mean an algorithm that increases similar to primes and is as best fit. And one that doesn't grow in complexity or is close to constant in time.

Why do I want that? Well for one thing it would of course be insightful as to finding an algorithm that creates real primes but for my purpose I specifically want it to be able to compare result I get for real primes with result I would get for faux primes (meaning something that just grows similar to primes).

Comment: If you mean something like a pre-test that is much faster than the probable-prim-test and giving a high probability that the number is prime, if the test is passed, I do not think that such a test exists.

Comment: If you only want a function growing approximately like the $n$-th-prime-function, the inverse of the function $Li(x)$ is a good choice.

Comment: Technically, one could output $2$ on any input and it would be a constant-time algorithm for outputting prime(s) :)